# Weird reputation jump

Tags: support, reputation

I used to have 291 reputation on StackOverflow, now I have 467. It seems like somebody upvoted many of my answers in one day...

I don't want people to get suspicious on me, what can I do?
Can I find out who did the upvotes?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. There a vote-fraud scripts in place. If it was one joker, then your rep will drop soon again. Just ignore it.

Comment: You really should have posted it as an answer.

Comment: Don't look a gift unicorn in the mouth.  Seriously, you'll be hit in the face with a rainbow.

Comment: As an aside, disassociate and reassociate your Super User account to get a 100 point bonus there too.

Comment: @Popular Demand - wrong end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all handled automatically; you don't have to do anything.

If voting anomalies persist for more than 24-36 hours email us at the address provided at the bottom of every web page, with as many details as you have.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the responsible of that BlaXpirit, I can remove my up votes if you prefer. I think we should not be able to upvote the same people too many times.

Comment: Why did you upvote BlaX so many times? As a joke, or because you browsed their answers and found them useful?

Comment: I liked the way BlaXpirit helped one member. But now I think that was not a good idea. Voting for the same person the same day is very rare, and should be avoided.